# A necessary and sufficient condition for a structure to be rigid.

Tags: model-theory

Is this a necessary and sufficient condition for a structure $M$ to be rigid: For all distinct $m, m'$ in the underlying set of $M$,  $Th(M,m) \neq Th(M,m')$?

Comment: At least one of these you should be able to answer quite immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Asaf points out in the comments, it is entirely straightforward that if $\text{Th}(M,m)\neq \text{Th}(M,m')$ for all distinct $m$ and $m'$ in $M$, then $M$ is rigid.

The converse is not true. *Hint:* Every ordinal $(\alpha,<)$ is rigid.

Comment: So, can you give me an ordinal and two distinct elements in it, such that their theories are the same? I am struggling to think of such an ordinal.

Comment: @user107952 The easiest argument is non-constructive: there are only continuum-many theories in a countable language, so any ordinal of cardinality greater than continuum must have two elements with the same complete theory.

Comment: But with a bit more work, it's possible to give explicit examples. I believe $\omega^\omega$ and $\omega^\omega\cdot 2$ have the same complete theory in $\omega^\omega \cdot 3$, for example.

Comment: I would try to prove this using an Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse game argument. Hint: using first-order formulas, you can express things like "$x$ is a successor ordinal", "$x$ is a limit ordinal", $x$ is a limit of limit ordinals", "$x$ is a the next largest limit of limit ordinals to a limit of limit of limit ordinals" etc. But when you get to $\omega^\omega$, which is a (limit of)$^n$ limit ordinals for all $n$, you can not longer capture this property in a first-order formula. By the way, the usual terminology for $\text{Th}(M, m)$ is the "complete type" of $m$ in $M$.